# Pro micro Wire.endTransmission() does not return

Tags: i2c, arduino-pro-micro, atmega32u4

I have an Arduino Pro Micro(blue version) and I'm having trouble using the I2C. To test it, I use the code below and the result is an infinite square wave on SCL and SDA lines and I only get the number 1 on the terminal output. I have pullup resistors on both wires, 2k each.
Since the board uses an ATMEGA32U4, I tried the same code on a bare MCU and the code works as expected. The difference between the two is the bootloader type. The bare PCB is flashed over USB, using the factory bootloader(ATMEGA32U4-AU, QFP44).
By debugging the code, I found out that endTransmission does not return.
Does anyone have an idea, why the I2C is not working as expected on the Pro Micro module?

Thanks!

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  // Leonardo: wait for serial port to connect
  while (!Serial)
    {
    }
  Serial.println ();
  Serial.println ("I2C scanner. Scanning ...");
  byte count = 0; 
  Wire.begin();
}  // end of setup

void loop() {
  byte count = 0;
  for (byte i = 1; i < 120; i++)
  {
    Serial.println(i);
    Wire.beginTransmission (i);
    Wire.endTransmission ();
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite square wave"? Does that mean, that both SDA and SCL get continuously pulsed forever, when `Wire.endTransmission()` blocks?

Comment: Yes, and it does not stop. The waveform looks good, signal level is VCC and GND for 1 and 0.

Comment: Mhh, strange. Does this also happen, when nothing is connected to the bus?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. With and without the pullup resistor.

Comment: To be clear, SCL and SDA have **nothing at all** attached to them but pullup resistors and perhaps your scope?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: And nothing is printing on the Serial Monitor? then I guess your microcontroller is broken. Your sketch seems legit to me. And the lines should never just pulse continuously. A common problem is the bus getting stuck, because one line gets stuck at low, but I haven't seen your problem ever. Can you tell us the frequency of the pulses? Just to check

Comment: Same thoughts as chrisl.  I suppose I should go a step further and ask: what happens if you have nothing connected to the Pro Micro at all except the USB cable?  No external pullup resistors; the internals that are enabled for Wire.begin() are sufficient for this test.  No scope.  Just the USB cable.  Pro Micro *not even* attached to a (solderless) breadboard, just the board sitting on something non-conductive.

Comment: I just bought a new pro micro and the I2C is working. Maybe the other one is really broken. Strange...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I dunno how useful it would be to anyone, but that seems to technically be **the answer** for your question.  So you could post it **as an answer** to your own question.  If you've accepted that it's the answer you can **accept** it as well, although as I understand it, you'll only be able to do that in a couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the module has a defect, since the same code on another board produces the expected output on the I2C lines